# Set variable to BitSlice in Rust

Tags: rust, bitvec

I am using the Rust [bitvec](https://docs.rs/bitvec/latest/bitvec/) crate to generate bit strings for a toy application involving
zlib compression. I have the following code for adding a bit string corresponding to a specific code point to a BitVec. I would like to be able to refer to the bit string using a variable, but that does not seem to be possible. Is there a better way to do this?

```rust
use bitvec::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut compressed = bitvec![u8, Lsb0;];
    let code_point = 127u8; // Arbitrary code point.

    // Ok, but awkward
    println!("{}",&(0b00110000u32 + code_point as u32).view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 8..]);
    compressed.extend(&(0b00110000u32 + code_point as u32).view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 8..]);

    //Won't compile: creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
    let code = &(0b00110000u32 + code_point as u32).view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 8..];
    println!("{}", code);
    compressed.extend(code);

    //Won't compile: doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    let code = (0b00110000u32 + code_point as u32).view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 8..];
    println!("{}", code);
    compressed.extend(&code);
}
```

Also, it would be nicer to be able to use `Lsb0` with `[..N]`, but the `reverse()` method cannot be chained.

--- EDIT ---

The actual case where I need this is slightly more complex than the above and looks something like this:

```rust
// This works
if code_point < 144 {
  compressed.extend(&(0b00110000u32 + code_point as u32).view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 8..])
} else {
  compressed.extend(&(0b110010000u32 + (code_point - 144) as u32).view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 9..])
};

// But I would like to write something like this:
let code = if code_point < 144 {
  &(0b00110000u32 + code_point as u32).view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 8..]
} else {
  &(0b110010000u32 + (code_point - 144) as u32).view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 9..]
};
compressed.extend(code);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the temporary to a variable to extend its lifetime:

```rust
let value = 0b00110000u32 + code_point as u32;
let code = &value.view_bits::<Msb0>()[32 - 8..];
```

Alternatively, since

Comment: Yes, that would work in my original example. I probably should have shown the real case instead.

Comment: @TrayMan the answer can be adapted for your real case: `let value; let code = if … { value = …; &value[…] } else { value = …; &value[…] };`

Comment: Cool! I would've never realized you can do that.